# Is there a way to pass a default object to require in nodejs?

Tags: json, node.js

I would like to do something like this:

```
var jsonFileName = aDynamicallyGeneratedJsonFileName(),
    defaultObject = {'my': 'default', 'json': 'object'};

var cachedOrRequiredObject = require(jsonFileName, defaultObject);
```

I would like for `cachedOrRequiredObject` to be given `defaultObject` if `jsonFileName` doesn't exist, and I would like for the require cache to keep `jsonFileName` as a key to `defaultObject` even when `jsonFileName` doesn't exist.

Of course this doesn't work -- in particular require errors when it can't find the file.  I could do something like:

```
function myRequire (file, defaultObj) {
   try {
       return require(file);
   catch () {
       return defaultObj;
   }
}
```

But every execution of `require` is going to hit the file system to try to find `file` when it doesn't exist.  Is there a better way for me to do this short of duplicating require's functionality and maintaining my own cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to maintain your own cache for non-existent files, `require` has no reason to do that. A very simple object cache is enough (and is what require() uses internally):

```
function requireWithDefault(path, default){
    var module
    if ((module = requireCache[path]) === undefined){
        try {
            module = require(path)
        } catch(e) {
            module = requireCache[path] = default
        }
    }
    return module
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for something more built in, but this isn't bad.